# Auto calculated column based on current & previous row data, that will be used for upcoming rows SQL, Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, erp

**Background**: An ERP tool that will hold all transaction information like opening balance & amount of transaction and closing balance of a user. The Opening Balance of the current row depends on the previous row's closing balance. The closing balance is calculated based on the addition or subtraction of the opening balance & amount of transaction. This calculated closing balance will be used as the next row's opening balance & further so on.

**Note:** The transaction information like the amount of transaction comes from product purchases that are there in the stock

**Problem:** Consider I have 100 entries. The administrator wants to change the 1st entry's amount of transaction for some reason. Due to this my closing balance of the first row will change. But the problem is all the other 99 rows depend on the first row's closing balance. How to create an SQL table that solves this depending column data problem.

**PS:** I'm using Django as the framework, but Raw SQL query & explanation will also solve my problem to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

You should really post your models...

But given a basic structure like this:

```py
from django.db import models, transaction
from django.utils import timezone


class Account(models.Model):
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=34, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self.mutations.last().end


class AccountMutation(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="mutations"
    )
    start = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=12)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=12)
    end = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=12)
    objects = AccountMutationManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("timestamp", "pk")
```

We can implement the custom manager like this:

```py
class AccountMutationManager(models.Manager):
    @transaction.atomic
    def recalculate(self, from_: "AccountMutation"):
        qs = self.filter(
            account=from_.account, timestamp__gte=from_.timestamp, id__gt=from_.id
        ).select_for_update()
        prev = from_
        for mutation in qs:
            mutation.start = prev.end
            mutation.end = mutation.start + mutation.amount
            mutation.save()
            prev = mutation
```

Of course, this is based on timestamp based mutations to determine ordering. If you link transactions, with a previous pointer, the selection is slightly different and you need a reorder() method in case a timestamp is changed. But this really depends on how it's stored.

Typically, I would not store start and end balance with mutations, but make them calculated fields and each account would have an opening balance for each "fiscal year", from which you start calculating.

Some clarifications:

- We use an all-or-nothing approach with atomic transactions
- in addition we lock all rows with `select_for_update()` that are going to be affected, so that no two recalculations can occur at the same time that affect the same data.
- `from_` is the mutation that was changed and assumed to have correct end balance